# Tkinter - SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax-error, keyword, keyword-argument

I have this problem I cannot understand, so in the delete button, where I try to delete the buttons after creating them, I have this error:

```
Delete=Button(root,text='Delete',command=lambda : S.pack_forget(),T.pack_forget())
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
Menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=Menubar)


def CreateButton():

    S=Button(root,text='Second Boton')
    S.pack(side='right')

    T=Button(root,text='Third Boton')
    T.pack(side='right')

    Delete=Button(root,text='Delete',command=lambda : S.pack_forget(),T.pack_forget())
    Delete.pack(side='right')


Create=Button(root,text='Create Boton',command=CreateButton)
Create.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change the line to `Delete=Button(root, text='Delete', command=lambda: (S.pack_forget(), T.pack_forget()))`. The problem was how the `lambda` expression was being parse and the `T.pack_forget()` was being interpreted as a non-keyword argument to the `Button` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You must put "[]" in the command to have access to use multiple commands.
Just edit it from :

```
Delete=Button(root,text='Delete',command=lambda : S.pack_forget(),T.pack_forget())
```

To :

```
Delete=Button(root,text='Delete',command=lambda : [S.pack_forget(),T.pack_forget()])
```